# Как получить Json файл в контроллере asp .net?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

начал изучать AJAX запросы и столкнулся с проблемой..
Есть View, в котором с помощью jquery отправляю ajax запрос:

```
        function isInCart(attrId) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Catalog/IsInCart",
            data: "{attrId:" + attrId + "}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.data);
            }
        });
    };
```

и контроллер, в котором хочу получить это значение

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult IsInCart(string json)
{
       
    return Json(new { data = data});
}
```

Но в контроллер ничего не приходит (json = null).
Почему так происходит?